# Retrieving the value of an NSProgressIndicator

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am trying to retrieve the value (how far along it is) of a Determinate NSProgressIndicator.
I have tried …

```
NSInteger *bValue = [progressIndicator doubleValue];
```

But it gives an error saying `Incompatible types in initialization`.
So how do I retrieve the value of the Progress Indicator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `NSInteger` is not an object type, it is simply a typedef for an `int` or `long` (dependent on whether your application is 32 or 64-bit):

```
#if __LP64__ || TARGET_OS_EMBEDDED || TARGET_OS_IPHONE || TARGET_OS_WIN32 || NS_BUILD_32_LIKE_64
typedef long NSInteger;
#else
typedef int NSInteger;
#endif
```

(From the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000018-DontLinkElementID_8))

Therefore, you can write it as:

```
NSInteger bValue = [progressIndicator doubleValue];
```

You are receiving an error because you are declaring `bValue` as a *pointer* to an `NSInteger`, yet trying to initialize it with a double value.

Comment: Ah, I see know why I get the error. So what should I put instead of NSInteger?

Comment: You can leave it as `NSInteger` if you want, you just need to omit the *. It depends on the level of precision you want – if you only need to know the integer value of the progress indicator, use `NSInteger`. If you want a higher amount of precision, use `float` or `double`.

Comment: I doesn't need to be that precise so `NSInteger` should be ok. Thanks!